# If deleting not last item from StringList gives error

Tags: delphi

I currently have an issue with the code

```
for i := 0 to stringlist1.count - 1 do
begin
  found := false;
  for j := 0 to stringList2.count - 1 do
  begin
    if stringList1[i] = stringList2[j] then
    begin
      found := true;
      break;
    end;
  end;
  if not found then
  begin
    stringlist1.delete(i); 
  end;
end;
```

If I have more than 1 item in the stringList1 and the item not found is first, or somewhere in the middle (not last) then I get an error: List index out of bounds(*)

If for example I have 2 items in stringList1, and delete last (2nd) then no error. if I delete 1st (not last) then error: List index ouf of bounds(1) appears.

I am not sure where to start to fix this.

Comment: When you delete the first item, you break the outer loop, because `stringlist1.count - 1` is read only during the first pass through the loop. Deleting an item means that there is one less item in the stringlist, so `stringlist1.count - 1` now is past the end of the stringlist. You always loop downward (for i := stringlist1.count - 1 downto 0` when deleting from a list of any sort.

Comment: *when deleting from a list of any sort* should be followed by *in a loop*.